# How can I get the value of these variables?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the value of the variables "latitude" and "longitude".

```
var latitude;
var longitude;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
  } else {
    alert("Request failed.")
  }
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Not sure how geocoder works, but I'd be surprised if `results[0].geometry.location.lat();` is correct. `lat` is more than likely an object attribute and not a function. Try removing the parens

Comment: it still returning "undefined"

Comment: Wowow.. Like u said it return the wrong latitude and longitude. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. It's an async call.

The way I handled something similar was to call your next function right after latitude and longitude are set.

For example:

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var latitude  = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      myNextFunction(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway. Breennan just said to me that this geocode does not work.

Comment: The geocoder does work, I just don't think you can get access to the longitude and latitude outside of where the variables are set. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It does not work. I have already test it. Im trying to get the latitude and longitude by the zip code. I just found a php script that is gonna help me on that.